# SignalR performance drops when SQL Server Service Broker is turned on

Tags: sql-server, signalr, service-broker

I am trying to setup SignalR for use in a load balanced environment with two web servers behind a load balancer and a separate database server.

I am using the SQL Server Backplane. As recommended in the official documentation, I at first turned on the Service Broker for the database. I observed that with the Service broker turned on Messages take much longer to get pushed from server to client. Why would this be the case ?

Comment: Because they first go to the database. And your database likely has a performance problem. Start profiling.

Comment: @TomTom They go to the database either way, whether the broker is on or off. But the delay I notice is there only when the broker is on.

Comment: Perhaps turning on service broker introduced the performance issue... in which case profiling (before and after) is still a good idea.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid The production environment is unfortunately very far out of my reach. I can pretty much do nothing after deploying the website and I can't reproduce the issue in the development environment.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you mean that the signalr scale out works without service broker enabled but docs say enable it? If so then just leave it disabled - if it works then don't worry about it!

Comment: You are asking for magic pixie dust: guess why performance modifies, w/o *any* data. Start by doing your homework first: [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/)

Comment: @TomRedfern It works either way. I was hoping someone might have come across the same issue and might be able to shed some light on this.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Maybe if you read the comments above, you'd know that I don't have access to the production environment.

Comment: @AliKazmi - I believe what RemusRusanu is getting at is that it is impossible to say what is going on without anything beyond the claim that "SignalR performance drops when service broker is turned on." Since, like you we have no view into your production environment. My suggestion like the others would be to work with your DBA to figure out 1. Is there a time they can run profiler against the production db to see what is happening. 2. If all else fails see if Service Broker can be turned off or you can move to a different back plane for the your SignalR hub like say - Redis or Service Bus.

Comment: @AliKazmi, did you ever find the root cause of this?  I found the same behavior running on my dev box.  With Service broker turned on, SignalR sends messages out at a snails pace.  With it turned off, it's close to instantaneous.

Comment: I am having the same problem on my dev box

Comment: I had the same issue in my dev environment. I think it's related to the SQL Server version you are running. Service broker works fine on production server, but locally we have to use Polling or not use it at all.